# Api Calling with cURL request not working on linux server

Tags: php, json, linux, api, curl

I am sending JSON data via API using a cURL request. It is working perfectly fine on my local server but when I am running the same on Linux sever using puTTy it's giving me error code 28.

```
$missed_date = $prev_day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year;
        $url = "abc";
        $api_data = array(
          "serverip" => "$sname", //sname is sever ip
          "date" => "$missed_date"
        );
        $postdata = json_encode($api_data);
        // Send API request
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        print_r($result);
        echo $result . $curl_errno;
```

Comment: _"it's giving me error code 28"_ - who/what is? The remote API? Putty? ...? If the API, have you looked up what that error code means in the documentation yet?

Comment: Check if remote server requires some authentication